# Good way to match symmetric delimiters

Tags: auctex, regular-expressions, polymode

I am trying to match `$$` resp `$` pairs to switch into latex-mode via `polymode` in a markdown file. `$$` is the delimiter for displayed math in this case and `$` for inline math.

I know that this is not a good choice for delimiters because they are symmetric. However latex-mode itself i.e. when editing an usual latex-document just recognizes those pairs very well.

So is there any good regular expression I can use in my code below instead of just looking for `$$` resp. `$`?

```
(require 'polymode)

(defcustom pm-host/markd
  (pm-bchunkmode "Markd"
                 :mode 'markdown-mode)
  "Markdown host chunkmode"
  :group 'hostmodes
  :type 'object)


(defcustom pm-inner/latex
  (pm-hbtchunkmode "latex"
           :mode 'latex-mode
           :head-reg  "\\$\\$\\|\\$"
           :tail-reg  "\\$\\$\\|\\$")
  "latex typical chunk."
  :group 'innermodes
  :type 'object)

(defcustom pm-poly/markdown-latex
  (pm-polymode-one "markdown-latex"
           :hostmode 'pm-host/markd
           :innermode 'pm-inner/latex)
  "markdown-python typical polymode."
  :group 'polymodes
  :type 'object)

(define-polymode poly-markdown+latex-mode pm-poly/markdown-latex)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mdwn\\'" . poly-markdown+latex-mode))
```

Comment: Could it be simply that you forgot to quote those `$` (which by default mean "match end of line" in regexps)?

Comment: @Stefan: You mean escape them via `\\$\\$\\|\\$`, I will try it ...

Comment: @Stefan: It doesn't work, for example it interprets the closing delimiter of a block as the opening delimiter of the next block (which is wrong).

Comment: what about using `\\$+` to match 1 or more `$`, instead of explicitly trying one (`\\$`) or two (`\\$\\$`)? That should treat `$` and `$$` the same, and shouldn't break unless you do weird things with `$` inside math mode, or use more than two `$` in some other context...

Comment: @Tyler: I tried it, but with the same result as described in the comment above.

Comment: I don't know whether this applies to `polymode` or even this task, but your question reminded me of an approach to detecting matching delimiter pairs I came across on the Emacs Wiki: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=ReplaceRegexp;id=ReplaceRegexpWithLispExpressions#toc13. The idea is to match every delimiter and use the current counter to determine whether it is an opening or closing delimiter. Of course, this only works for non-nested delimiters.